# How to fix a variable from a class not being subtracted in a method?

Tags: java, class, methods

The gist of this assignment is that there are two players who take a stick out of a pile. I made a class that has the number of sticks available. There is a method that is called to remove sticks. However when I try to remove sticks the number of sticks doesn't change. Therefore the game not being able to end because there are still sticks "left".

I've tried using int sticks to be subtracted. The total amount of sticks changes but only in the method in which they are subtracted. The number of sticks don't change in the main method.

I decided to make use classes as I saw on this site that that is how this issue can be fixed. I've had no success with it.

So I made a class that has the amount of sticks so now the number of sticks is the same for each method. The same issue persists. One that changes the number of sticks in the getSticksRemove() method but not main() or getSticksLeft().

```
    //Main Class
    public class Main {
    //Method to remove sticks which considers different scenarios.
        public static int getSticksRemove(int sticks) {
            sticks = StickPile.getValue(StickPile.value);
            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            print ("How many sticks to remove?(1-3)");
            int x = input.nextInt();

            if( x>=1 && x<=3) {
                sticks -= x;
            }else if(sticks < 3 && x ==2 ) {
                print("Not enough sticks left.");
                getSticksRemove(sticks);

            }else if (x>3) {
                sticks -=3;
            }else {    `enter code here`
                sticks-=1;
        }
        print(sticks);
        return sticks;
    }
//Main method


    public static void main(String [] args) {
        StickPile stickPile = new StickPile();

        int turnP1 = 0;
        int turnP2 = 0;
        int sticks = 0;

    print("How many sticks are there initially? (1-100)");
        StickPile.setValue();
        sticks = StickPile.getValue(StickPile.value);

//This is the loop that determines when to stop the game

        while(sticks != 0) {
            System.out.print("Player 1: ");
            getSticksRemove(sticks);
            getSticksLeft(sticks);
            turnP1++;

            System.out.print("Player 2: ");
            getSticksRemove(sticks);
            getSticksLeft(sticks);
            turnP2++;
        }
        if(turnP1 % 2 == 0 && turnP2 % 2 == 1) {
            System.out.println("P2 Loses");
        }else {
            System.out.println("P1 Loses");
        }
    }
}

// This StickPile class is the one I made to store the number of sticks.


public class StickPile {
    static Scanner input  = new Scanner(System.in);
    public static int value;

    public static void setValue() {
        value = input.nextInt();
        }

    public static int getValue(int x) {
        x = value;
        System.out.println(x);
        return x;
    }
```

I expect to enter a number of sticks to remove from the pile. Ex. PileAmount: 20--> Remove: 12--> PileAmount: 8.

```
However, I get Ex. PileAmoun: 20 --> Remove: 5--> PileAmount: 20,
```

Comment: you never assign the return alue of the method

Comment: @Jens Which method?

Comment: The get methods return value which must be assigned to a variable.

Answer (score 0):

You're ignoring the return of `getSticksRemove`. You can't reassign the parameter to effect the number outside of the function.

Just use the return value:

```
sticks = getSticksRemove(sticks)
```

Make that change in both places.